# Set the user agent on android application

Tags: android, user-agent

I am developping a radio stream application for android through Eclipse, I would like to change the user-agent for my app so when someone is playing the shoutcast stream, I can see remotely on the icecast/shoutcast admin the user agent as i.e xxxx instead of stagefright 1.2

I am using MediaPlayer to play the stream

I have found the following

"You need to overwrite HTTPDataSource.cpp (see HTTPDataSource::read_at). And then inject it to the core of media player. :) look at this research first - The flow of events during the Media Player Creation in Android Framework"

but where is HTTPDataSource.cpp  locate, has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MediaPlayer to stream your media content directly, there is no direct way to set the user-agent. Internally MediaPlayer may be using the HTTPDataSource.cpp to get the content for streaming. If that is the case then you need to modify it and recompile the framework flush into your device then run it (which is useless if you are only providing service, many user will not flush their device just to run an application).

You can try a more painful way but that may or may not succeed, As you are using http-stream you can get http content and write the payload data to device (making a mp3 file or whatever) then use that mp3 to fake stream in MediaPlayer. You can add header string to HttpHost (User-Agent string?) while receiving the http content.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer class provides `setDataSource()`:

```
public void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers);
```

In you app which controls MediaPlayer instance, pass the user agent in the header map as follows:

```
Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();;
headerMap.put("User-Agent", "my user agent value");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri, headerMap);
```

It overrides the default user agent string (stagefright/1.x (Linux; Android x.x)).